# Adjusting Polygon Borders in D3 Map

Tags: javascript, d3.js, gis

I have a map of Haiti with administrative borders for each commune created using the D3 JavaScript library.

Please see the map of Haiti to the southeast of the USA. If I zoom in on the map, the borders for the communes appear to be accurately drawn. However, the lines are very think. How can modify the borders, creating thin lines or ideally thin dashed lines?

See below my JavaScript code (
http://jsfiddle.net/mattbowlby/a0od8d50/):

```
     ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      //                                                                               //
      //     Zoom Listener, Zoom Listener Function and Zoom Reset                      //
      //                                                                               //
      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

      // Define Zoom Function Event Listener
      function zoomFunction() {
        d3.selectAll("path")
          .attr("transform",
              "translate(" + d3.event.translate
              + ") scale (" + d3.event.scale + ")");
      }

      // Define Zoom Behavior
      var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
          .scaleExtent([.2, 200])
          .on("zoom", zoomFunction);

      // Define Zoom Reset
      function zoomReset() {
        zoom.scale(1);
        zoom.translate([0,0]);
      }



      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      //                                                                               //
      //     Visualization Creation                                                    //
      //                                                                               //
      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

      // Variables
      var width = 930,
          height = 400,
          geoPath = d3.geo.path();

      // Redefine the geoPath projection as mercator
      geoPath.projection(d3.geo.mercator)


      // SVG Viewport
      var svgContainer = d3.select("#viz").append("svg")
          .attr("width", width)
          .attr("height", height)
          .style("border", "2px solid red")
          .call(zoom);

      // Function to Draw Originally and then ReDraw the chart
      function draw(projection) {

        /*
         * Reset the Drawing by deleting old paths and reseting zoom level
         */

        // Delete prior paths
        d3.select("svg").selectAll("path").remove();

        //  Reset Zoom
        zoomReset();

        /*
         * redefine geoPath and Do 2 separate AJAX calls for USA and Haiti Paths
         */

        // Define geoPath Variable;
        var geoPath = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);


        // USA AJAX Call
        d3.json("https://rawgit.com/mattbowlby/b4a95151d65cc1326e6f/raw/8f487e1d18e5fc7b2fcc9fa0dfcab3fb03aeca13/usa.geo.json", function(error, data) {

          // Define Data
          var usaFeatureCollection = data;

          // Create USA Map SVG Path
          var usaSVG = svgContainer
            .append("path")
              .attr("d", geoPath(usaFeatureCollection))
              .style("fill", "navy");

        });


        // Haiti AJAX Call
        d3.json("https://rawgit.com/mattbowlby/b4a95151d65cc1326e6f/raw/0497f54fdd7fe9e2dc5a3e5da4d86f89d1a764a4/haiti3.geo.json", function(error, data) {

          // Define Data
          var haitiFeatureCollection = data;

          // Create Haiti Map SVG Path
          var haitiSVG = svgContainer
            .append("path")
              .attr("d", geoPath(haitiFeatureCollection))
              .style("fill", "blue")
              .style("stroke", "black");

        });


      }

      // Original Drawing
      draw(d3.geo.albers());

      // Tool tips
      var tip = d3.tip()
        .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
        .offset([-10, 0])
        .html(function(d) {
        return "<strong>Commune:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.id_com + "</span>";
  })
```

Comment: Set the `stroke-width` attribute on the `path` elements.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I added .style("stroke-width", 0.1); and it shows a nice thin border as I wanted. I appreciate it.